# Implementar URL limpias con htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Estoy trantando de implementar url limpias por medio de htaccsess, la primera vez se presiona el link funciona, pero si se presiona nuevamente no borra la url anterior, se añade al final de la ruta, adjunto codigo e imagenes de ejemplo.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^categoria/(.+)$ categoria.php?id_cat=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

El link en la pagina index.php es  `<a href="categoria/2">` y se direcciona a  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]. hasta ahi todo bien.

Luego en la pagina categoria.php  estan los mismos links `<a href="categoria/2">` pero esta vez al pasar por sobre el link se duplica la url [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así sucede cada vez que presiono el mismo link, solo cambia el id segun el que elija pero mantiene toda la url anterior : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Si con "pasar por sobre el link" te referís a que antes de clickear ya se ve que la URL está mal, entonces tenés un problema en como estás armando las URLs desde PHP o directamente en HTML (probablemente sean relativas y no absolutas). No creo que sea un problema del .htaccess.

Comment: Edite la pregunta, ya que los links no se especificaron, pero los link tanto en la pagina index.php y categoria.php son  <a href="categoria/2">  solo varia el id de la categoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando URLs relativas de una manera incorrecta, por eso se "duplica" la URL al hacer click en un link.

Si estás en la URL `https://tusitio.cl/ecom_desa/categoria/2` y hacés click en una URL relativa `categoria/2`, lo que va a pasar es que el último segmento de la URL actual (en éste caso el `2`) va a ser reemplazado por tu link; lo que da como resultado: `https://tusitio.cl/ecom_desa/categoria/categoria/2`.

Tenés 2 opciones:

URLs absolutas:

```
<a href="https://tusitio.cl/ecom_desa/categoria/2">Link</a>
<a href="/ecom_desa/categoria/2">Link</a>
```

URLs relativas:

```
<a href="../categoria/2">Link</a>
```

Comment: funcionó!!, muchas gracias